# How do I make the "plus sign" in Treeview follow indentations?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, parent-child, indentation

So, I am trying to make a database program for my needs, and to make it more visible attractive I want the plus sign to follow indentation from the files and folders it reads from a database? This is going to be a parent/child kind of view.

Here is what I want:
[The open and closing +/- symbol follows the filename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr9Kx.png)

The code for this I found during researching into this exact problem, but I cant differentiate the code to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is what I currently have:
[Not following, and it seems to be appearing on its separate columns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQAUw.png)

I've tried to add and remove columns, because to me, it seems like the problem is that they are being printed to their own column.

Here is my code (The code I found when searching is pasted at the bottom, I'm sorry to the author, I didnt make a not of where I found it.) (If you run it the scrollbar is way off btw..):

```
class FiletreeInfoApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
        self.root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width, height))
        
        # Window Title
        app_title = "File Structure Info"
        self.root.title(app_title)

        # Upper and lower Frames
        self.upper_frame = ttk.Frame(self.root, relief="sunken", height=120)
        self.upper_frame.pack(fill="x", pady=15, padx=30)

        self.lower_frame = ttk.Frame(self.root, relief="sunken")
        self.lower_frame.pack(fill="both", padx=15, pady=15, expand=True)

        # Lower frames' Treeview
        self.db_reader = ttk.Treeview(self.lower_frame, columns=("#0"), height=8)

        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.db_reader, orient='vertical', command=self.db_reader.yview)
        xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.db_reader, orient='horizontal', command=self.db_reader.xview)

        self.db_reader.configure(yscroll=ysb.set, xscroll=xsb.set)
        self.db_reader.heading('#0', text='Path', anchor='w')
        self.db_reader.column('#0', minwidth=25, width=70)

        self.db_reader.pack(padx=30, pady=30, fill="both", side="left", expand=True)

        ysb.pack(fill="y", anchor="e")
        xsb.pack(fill="x", anchor="s")

        self.info_entry = ttk.Entry(self.lower_frame)
        self.info_entry.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
```

If I also try to remove the "columns="#0"" from the creation of the Treeview widget, I get what I want, but then nothing show up. Every entry is blank.
[Every entry is blank, but indentation seems fine, just need the text in there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb1fB.png)

Here is the code I found:

```
import os
try:
    # Python2
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class DirectoryBrowser(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, path):
        self.path = os.path.abspath(path)
        self.entries = {"": self.path}
        self.root = None

        # setup treeview and scrollbars

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)

        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)

        self.tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set, xscroll=xsb.set)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Path', anchor='w')
        self.tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", self.update_subtree)

        # fill treeview with root dir and the subdirs
        iid = self.insert("", "end", self.path)
        self.tree.focus(iid)
        self.process_directory(iid, self.path)

        # add tree and scrollbars to frame
        self.tree.grid(in_=self, row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        ysb.grid(in_=self, row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        xsb.grid(in_=self, row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.Y)

        # testing ...
        # returns a list of children belonging to last iid
        print(self.tree.get_children(iid))

    def insert(self, parent, index, path, name="", **kwargs):
        """
        add new element to TreeView
        """
        if "text" in kwargs:
            err = "arg 'text' not available"
            raise ValueError(err)

        kwargs["text"] = path
        if name:
            kwargs["text"] = name

        iid = self.tree.insert(parent, index, **kwargs)
        self.entries[iid] = path
        return iid

    def process_directory(self, parent, path, depth=3):
        if depth == 0:
            return
        for p in os.listdir(path):
            abspath = os.path.join(path, p)
            if os.path.isdir(abspath):
                iid = self.insert(parent,
                                  'end',
                                  path=abspath,
                                  name=p,
                                  open=False)
                self.process_directory(iid, abspath, depth-1)

    # Callbacks

    def update_subtree(self, event):
        iid = self.tree.focus()
        path = self.entries[iid]
        print("%s: %s" % (iid, path))
        print(iid in self.entries.keys())
        #self.process_directory(iid, path)


def test():
    root = tk.Tk()
    mypath = "F:\\Github_bittib010"
    app = DirectoryBrowser(root, path=mypath)
    # testing ...
    print(app.tree.get_children())  #  returns root children
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Edit as answer to a question.
I used a for loop in its own function to open, add, commit and close. Here is the for-loop and the sqlite statement:

```
'''
    # Execute command
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM Windows10")
    records = c.fetchall()

    # Add data to ttk treeview
    counter = 0
    for record in records:
        self.db_reader.insert('', tk.END, values=record[1], iid=record[0], open=False)
        if counter != 0:
            self.db_reader.move(record[0], record[5], counter)'''
```

Comment: where is original code for `db_reader.insert()`. Differencet has to be in `insert()`. You should compare parameter used to add items. First column has special name (`#0`) and it also need special method to add text

Comment: when I run your code on linux then I see all text correctly

Comment: Added an answer to the OP.

Comment: Do you happen to have example of what kind of special method to add text to that column?

Comment: as I said before: your code works correctly on my Linux - I can see all text in first column - so code seems OK and I have no idea why it doesn't work on Windows. And I said before: where is original code which you found on internet - we can't compare it with your current code if you don't show FULL code from internet.

Comment: You need to use `text` argument of `Treeview.insert(...)` to put text in the *tree column* (i.e. "#0") where the *"plus sign"* will be shown.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot, that worked!